# d3.js line chart with negative numbers

Tags: d3.js

I have a working d3.js line chart that renders linear numbers: http://jsfiddle.net/2g9VQ/

```
    var probArray = ["1.0", "0.999999931839", "0.999816434171", "0.994147880224", "0.961785353466", "0.882923015661", "0.763731336472", "0.627901360001", "0.497594590727", "0.385100568858", "0.256161790111", "0.168894610653", "0.111773057", "0.0747467808441", "0.051065424573", "0.0355360834346", "0.0251527408762", "0.018097770"];
    var imlArray = ["2.0", "4.0", "6.0", "8.0", "10.0", "12.0", "14.0", "16.0", "18.0", "20.0", "23.0", "26.0", "29.0", "32.0", "35.0", "38.0", "41.0", "44.0", "47.0", "50.0", "55.0", "60.0", "65.0", "70.0", "75.0", "80.0", "85.0", "90.0", "95.0", "100.0", "110.0", "120.0", "130.0", "140.0", "150.0", "160.0", "170.0", "180.0", "190.0", "200.0", "220.0", "240.0", "260.0", "280.0", "300.0"];

    function log(n) {
      return Math.log(n) / Math.LN10;
    }
    var data = [];
    for(i=0; i<probArray.length; i++) {
        // without log values...
        data.push([parseFloat(imlArray[i]), parseFloat(probArray[i])]);

        // with log valuse...
        //data.push([log(parseFloat(imlArray[i])), log(parseFloat(probArray[i]))]);
    }
    console.log(data);

    var margin = {top: 20, right: 20, bottom: 50, left: 50},
    width = 400 - margin.left - margin.right,
    height = 320 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

    var x = d3.time.scale().range([0, width]);
    var y = d3.scale.linear().range([height, 0]);
    var xAxis = d3.svg.axis().scale(x).orient("bottom");
    var yAxis = d3.svg.axis().scale(y).orient("left");

    var line = d3.svg.line()
        .x(function(d) { return x(d.x); })
        .y(function(d) { return y(d.y); });

    var svg = d3.select("#dialog").append("svg")
        .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
        .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
        .append("g")
        .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

    var dataCallback = function(d) {
        d.x = +d[0];
        d.y = +d[1];
    };

    data.forEach(dataCallback);
    x.domain(d3.extent(data, function(d) { return d.x; }));
    y.domain([0, d3.max(data, function(d) { return d.y; })]);
    svg.append("path")
        .data([data])
        .attr("class", "line")
        .attr("d", line);
    svg.append("g")
        .attr("class", "x axis")
        .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
        .call(xAxis)
        .append("text")
        .attr("x", 160)
        .attr("y", 30)
        .attr("dy", ".71em")
        .style("text-anchor", "end")
        .text("Intensity measure type");
    svg.append("g")
        .attr("class", "y axis")
        .call(yAxis)
        .append("text")
        .attr("transform", "rotate(-90)")
        .attr("y", -50)
        .attr("dy", ".71em")
        .style("text-anchor", "end")
        .text("Probabability of exceedance in "+invest_time+" years");

    var legend = d3.select("#dialog").append("svg");

    legend.append("text")
        .attr("x", 20)
        .attr("y", 7)
        .attr("dy", ".35em")
        .text("Location (Lon/Lat): "+lng+", "+lat);

    d3.select('#chart').on("click", function() {
            data.splice(0,1);
            data.push([5,5]);
            dataCallback(data[data.length - 1]);

    x.domain(d3.extent(data, function(d) { return d.x; }));
    y.domain([0, d3.max(data, function(d) { return d.y; })]);
      svg.selectAll("path").data([data])
          .attr("d", line);
    });
```

But the chart fails to render when I change the points to a logarithmic scale: http://jsfiddle.net/Z3Yms/

```
    var probArray = ["1.0", "0.999999931839", "0.999816434171", "0.994147880224", "0.961785353466", "0.882923015661", "0.763731336472", "0.627901360001", "0.497594590727", "0.385100568858", "0.256161790111", "0.168894610653", "0.111773057", "0.0747467808441", "0.051065424573", "0.0355360834346", "0.0251527408762", "0.018097770"];
    var imlArray = ["2.0", "4.0", "6.0", "8.0", "10.0", "12.0", "14.0", "16.0", "18.0", "20.0", "23.0", "26.0", "29.0", "32.0", "35.0", "38.0", "41.0", "44.0", "47.0", "50.0", "55.0", "60.0", "65.0", "70.0", "75.0", "80.0", "85.0", "90.0", "95.0", "100.0", "110.0", "120.0", "130.0", "140.0", "150.0", "160.0", "170.0", "180.0", "190.0", "200.0", "220.0", "240.0", "260.0", "280.0", "300.0"];

    function log(n) {
      return Math.log(n) / Math.LN10;
    }
    var data = [];
    for(i=0; i<probArray.length; i++) {
        // without log values...
        //data.push([parseFloat(imlArray[i]), parseFloat(probArray[i])]);

        // with log valuse...
        data.push([log(parseFloat(imlArray[i])), log(parseFloat(probArray[i]))]);
    }
    console.log(data);

    var margin = {top: 20, right: 20, bottom: 50, left: 50},
    width = 400 - margin.left - margin.right,
    height = 320 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

    var x = d3.time.scale().range([0, width]);
    var y = d3.scale.linear().range([height, 0]);
    var xAxis = d3.svg.axis().scale(x).orient("bottom");
    var yAxis = d3.svg.axis().scale(y).orient("left");

    var line = d3.svg.line()
        .x(function(d) { return x(d.x); })
        .y(function(d) { return y(d.y); });

    var svg = d3.select("#dialog").append("svg")
        .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
        .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
        .append("g")
        .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

    var dataCallback = function(d) {
        d.x = +d[0];
        d.y = +d[1];
    };

    data.forEach(dataCallback);
    x.domain(d3.extent(data, function(d) { return d.x; }));
    y.domain([0, d3.max(data, function(d) { return d.y; })]);
    svg.append("path")
        .data([data])
        .attr("class", "line")
        .attr("d", line);
    svg.append("g")
        .attr("class", "x axis")
        .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
        .call(xAxis)
        .append("text")
        .attr("x", 160)
        .attr("y", 30)
        .attr("dy", ".71em")
        .style("text-anchor", "end")
        .text("Intensity measure type");
    svg.append("g")
        .attr("class", "y axis")
        .call(yAxis)
        .append("text")
        .attr("transform", "rotate(-90)")
        .attr("y", -50)
        .attr("dy", ".71em")
        .style("text-anchor", "end")
        .text("Probabability of exceedance in "+invest_time+" years");

    var legend = d3.select("#dialog").append("svg");

    legend.append("text")
        .attr("x", 20)
        .attr("y", 7)
        .attr("dy", ".35em")
        .text("Location (Lon/Lat): "+lng+", "+lat);

    d3.select('#chart').on("click", function() {
            data.splice(0,1);
            data.push([5,5]);
            dataCallback(data[data.length - 1]);

    x.domain(d3.extent(data, function(d) { return d.x; }));
    y.domain([0, d3.max(data, function(d) { return d.y; })]);
      svg.selectAll("path").data([data])
          .attr("d", line);
    });
```

I believe this is due to the numbers becoming negative along the y axis.

Comment: It looks like your x axis is a time scale. Did you want a linear scale there?

Comment: And yes, all your values are negative and your y scale starts at 0. If you remove that it works without problems -- http://jsfiddle.net/Z3Yms/1/

Comment: Ah, you are right, that was not intended, but even when I change it to a linear scale the log values are not rendering.

Comment: Great, I'll add that as an answer for reference.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You were setting the domain of the y axis as

```
y.domain([0, d3.max(data, function(d) { return d.y; })]);
```

which with the log values won't work because all values are less than 0. To fix, simply use

```
y.domain(d3.extent(data, function(d) { return d.y; }));
```

instead. You also might want to use a linear scale instead of a time scale for the x axis. Complete jsfiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/Z3Yms/1/).